# Alternative term for "recover" in case of trivial problems

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

Normally after we get rid of a severe disease, we use the term 'recover'.

**I just recovered from Cancer or Tuberculosis.**

If it was just a trivial headache/cold, how would we say it?

> I just ___ from a headache.

If you have any other way of saying the same, please do not hold yourself back.

Comment: You could say "My cold has *cleared up.*" - you may be less likely to say that about a headache, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may **perk up** (*gain or regain energy; become more cheerful, hopeful, or lively*).

> Example: If you want to *perk up* from a hangover, do coffee and tea
>   help?

Comment: Thank you. It's nice. Is it usable in case of a muscular pain? If one sprained his back a while ago which lasted for 2-3 days.

Comment: You can perk up from any medical problem (severe or mild), e.g. " perk up from Iron Deficiency Anemia".

Comment: +1 to your answer for now. I'll wait for a while now and if nobody comes up with a better alternative, you'll have a green tick :)

Comment: @Graffito   "Perk up" is fine for all "trivial problems", which is what the OP asked for in his Question.  But then he added back problems, which, in my age group at least, are rarely trivial and from which people do not perk up without the aid of powerful chemicals.  They work their way out of them.  Hence my Answer.

Answer (score 3):

*I just [**got over**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+over+a+cold%2Cgot+over+cancer%2Cgot+over+tuberculosis%2Crecovered+from+a+cold%2Crecovered+from+cancer%2Crecovered+from+tuberculosis&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20over%20a%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecovered%20from%20a%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecovered%20from%20cancer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecovered%20from%20tuberculosis%3B%2Cc0) a headache.*

> get over: recover from

[**American Heritage Dictionary**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get+over)

Answer (score 1):

For a muscular pain, one usually says ***"it is better***", or **"the ice pack really helped"** or **"the massage did the trick"** or **"the whirlpool gave me a lot of relief".**  Or some such remedy.

Muscular pains often linger and can be retriggered by doing too soon the action that caused them in the first place.  A back pain is particularly likely to recur if you do not analyze what went wrong and correct your movements.  All this is to say that "perk up" is a pretty optimistic phrase for a muscular pain, especially a back pain, unless you had cortisone.

(This answer may not be responsive to "trivial problems", which the OP asked in his Question, but is responsive to his Comment, above, about back problems.)

Comment: Great. Thanks. I like the alternative wording! And I used trivial because I am just used to it now, happens many times to me. (4-5 times a year which is not very common in my age group)